# SelectAction fails: Multiple actions were found. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've installed the Web-Api Route Debugger to try and figure out what is going on here and it reports the following exception:-

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetTasksByParentAndList(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32) on type AcademicStudio.WebHost.Controllers.TasksController
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetTasksByListTreeAndDepartmentAndTerms(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32[], Int32[]) on type AcademicStudio.WebHost.Controllers.TasksController
  Source=System.Web.Http
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
       at AcademicServer.WebHost.Areas.RouteDebugger.InspectActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) in d:\AcademicServer\AcademicServer.WebHost\Areas\RouteDebugger\InspectActionSelector.cs:line 42
       at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()
       at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
  InnerException:
```

The two actions are both declared in the controller with the ActionName attribute as follows: (and have different parameters).

```
[ActionName("ParentAndList")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTasksByParentAndList(Int32 parentId, Int32 listId, Int32 fromId, Int32 toId)
{
    var service = new TaskService();
    var data = service.SelectTasksByParentAndList(parentId, listId, fromId, toId);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}

[ActionName("ListTreeAndDepartmentAndTerms")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTasksByListTreeAndDepartmentAndTerms(Int32 parentId, Int32 listId, Int32 fromId, Int32 toId, [FromUri]Int32[] defs, [FromUri]Int32[] depts)
{
    var service = new TaskService();
    var data = service.SelectTasksByListTreeAndDepartmentAndTerms(parentId, listId, fromId, toId, defs, depts);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?  The controller contains many other actions declared with ActionName which work just fine.

**Update**.

Ten minutes after posting the question I figured it out: MapHttpRoutes were not properly configured in WebApiConfig.cs

Why is it that you can stare at something all morning and ten minutes after giving up and asking a question the penny finally drops?